# Best and quickest way to parse large XML

Tags: json, xml, xml-parsing

I don't really care about what programming language to use as long as it supported in Linux.

The point is reading XML files and convert them to json array with mapping key to json key. 
What I've tried already. 
PHP

- using `simplexml_load_file`
- quick parsing
- single threaded
- not so well memory management

Python

- using minidom.parse
- slow parsing
- multiprocessing pool gets stuck
- awesome memory management

NodeJs

- usibg xml2js
- slow parsing
- a bit multiprocessing using async
- not good memory management

What can I do to make it faster. Thanks.

Edit:
The importance about multi processing is that I have 50 XML's multiplied by 5 directories

This producer should run once an hour

Comment: How do you compare the quality of memory management? What do you expect from multiprocessing? This conversion is actually a classic sequential operation.

Comment: A. Comparing memory using ps aux or top commands. B. For multi file conversation

Comment: I see. So you want to convert about 250 files. Are they to be converted once or repeatedly? In other words, what's the expected frequency of such conversion? Once? Once per hour? Once per minute? Once per second? Are there other constraints?

Comment: Once per hour. The average is 250 can be bit more or less. The average file size is 20M

Comment: The easy way: [XSLTJSON: Transforming XML to JSON using XSLT](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the speed and memory are an issue and if you don't mind a little bit of coding, perhaps it would be reasonable to use **stream parsers** such as [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) or [xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse).